# Including typings from the piral instance fails

Tags: reactjs, typescript, piral

I have already found out how to properly type plugins in piral (by using declaration merging).

This only seems to work for pilet api extensions coming from dedicated packages and also only if there is an api.d.ts in its root folder.

How can I type pilet api extensions that are defined directly in the piral instance?

What I tried so far:

1. Placing an api.d.ts in the src folder
2. Placing the relevant typings directly in the src/index.tsx file
3. Changing the typings field in the package.json to either one (and others like src/types.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried placing the *api.d.ts* adjacent to the *package.json*? That should work!

Besides that the *api.d.ts* can be as simple as follows:

```
export { MyPiletApi} from './src/types';
```

Hope that helps!